# Why doesn't WPF border control have a mousedoubleclick event?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Why doesn't WPF border control have a mousedoubleclick event?  I have a ItemsControl with some layout stuff in it for a DataTemplate.  I want to handle the double click event to pop up a details dialog, but the border, my layout container, doesn't appear to expose the event.

Any suggestions on how to either get at the double click event, or rework the xaml to make it possible?

Answer (score 67):

Just use InputBindings.

```
<Border>
    <Border.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="..."/>
    </Border.InputBindings>
</Border>
```

In general; avoid using events if not developing controls in WPF. Usually the usage of code behind based events is a strong indication for a MVVM Pattern break.

Comment: Rarely do I come across the perfect answer to my question so quickly on stackoverflow

Comment: Elegant solution. Better than defining own doubleclick behavior.

Answer (score 16):

MouseDoubleClick is declared on Control so you just need an instance of some Control in your ItemTemplate. The simplest thing to do is use the base Control class which doesn't have any other behavior and just give it a customized template with what's in your ItemTemplate now.

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Control MouseDoubleClick="Control_MouseDoubleClick">
                <Control.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border>
                            <!--Other ItemTemplate stuff-->
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Control.Template>
            </Control>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: You can also use `ContentControl` and specify content instead of a template.

Answer (score 7):

Update: Sorry, my bad - late hour

Inside your mouse button down event get ClickCount

```
 //  e.Handled = true;  optional

 if (e.ClickCount > 1)
 {
    // here comes double click and more :)
 }
```

Comment: Stackpanel doesnt have a double click event either.  what are you suggesting I do with it?