# Bind list to listboxitem in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox

I'm trying to bind a list to a listbox in WPF. But it doesn't seem to work, I just see nothing on screen.

Here is my code:

**WPF**

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="453" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" Margin="0,43,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding orderlist}">
        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding orderlist.ID}"></ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

**C#**

```
Order order = new Order();
Klantgegevens klantgegevens = new Klantgegevens();
            XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\EDI\Rekening.xml");
            rdr.ReadToFollowing("datum");
            order.DatumOntvangst = rdr.ReadElementContentAsString();
            rdr.ReadToFollowing("volgnr");
            order.Status = "Aangenomen";
            order.Opmerkingen = "";
            rdr.ReadToFollowing("naam");
            order.Afzender = rdr.ReadElementContentAsString();
            rdr.ReadToFollowing("naam");
            klantgegevens.Naam = rdr.ReadElementContentAsString();
            rdr.ReadToFollowing("straat");
            klantgegevens.Straat = rdr.ReadElementContentAsString();
            rdr.ReadToFollowing("huisnr");
            klantgegevens.Huisnummer = rdr.ReadElementContentAsInt();
            rdr.ReadToFollowing("plaats");
            klantgegevens.Woonplaats = rdr.ReadElementContentAsString();
            rdr.ReadToFollowing("postcode");
            klantgegevens.Postcode = rdr.ReadElementContentAsString();
            rdr.ReadToFollowing("telefoonnr");
            klantgegevens.Telefoonnummer = rdr.ReadElementContentAsString();
            order.Klantgegevens = klantgegevens;
            orderlist.Add(order);
            listBox.DataContext = orderlist;
```

As you probably know, Order is a custom class, and so is Klantgegevens.
I'm pretty new to binding and WPF in general so excuse me for my stupidness :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set or bind the ItemsSource property of ListView to an IEnumerable. Since you have set the DataContext property to your "orderlist" you should bind the ItemsSource property directly to the DataContext (ItemsSource="{**Binding**}"). You should also use an ItemTemplate as suggested by Fruchtzwerg :

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="453" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" Margin="0,43,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
            </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Also note that the DataContext of the ItemTemplate is an item in your ItemsSource, i.e. an Order object in this case. So to bind to the "ID" property of the Order object you use the binding syntax above. "ID" must be a public property of the Order class.

Comment: Thanks it's one step in the right direction I guess, but it only works the first time I add something to the list

Comment: If you want to be able to add items to the ListBox dynamically at runtime you should set the ItemsSource property to an ObservableCollection<Order> instead of a List<Order>. An ObservableCollection provides change notifications but a List doesn't: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: One last question if I may,

How can I make an event for an item in that listbox. Say if I want to see what text is in the clicked item

Comment: That's another question really but you could for example handle the MouseLeftButtonDown event for the root element in your ItemTemplate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213030/double-click-event-on-wpf-window-border

Answer (score 1):

With

```
<ListBoxItem Content="{Binding orderlist.ID}"></ListBoxItem>
```

you are adding an item in XAML. But your plan is to create a template to present bound items. The simplest solution is to use

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" DisplayMemberPath="ID"/>
```

if only one property needs to be presented. Multiple properties can be showed by creating a template like

```
<ListView x:Name="listBox">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding datum}"/>
                                <!-- ... -->
                        </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Furthermore you should use a property like

```
public ObservableCollection<Klantgegevens> Items { get; } =
    new ObservableCollection<Klantgegevens>();
```

to bind on. Set the `DataContext` of the whole Window with the `ListView` to the object, with this property. After that you can bind the ListView with

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```