# How to fire double click event in a combobox in a child user control?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a user control that use another user control. The child user control has a combobox and the click event works because i can open the combobox, but the double click it doesn't work.

My code is this:

Main user control:

```
<StackPanel>
    <views:ucMyChildUserControl/>
</StackPanel>
```

My child user control:

```
<StackPanelOrientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label Content="Content" Style="{StaticResource LabelDefault}"/>
        <ComboBox Name="cmbMyCombobox"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--More related controls-->
    
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</StackPanel>
```

But I have realized that if the comand of mouse double click is set in the parent user control, it works:

```
<views:ucChildUserControl>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</views:ucChildUserControl>
```

So I guess the problem is about the handling of the event, but I don't know how to catch it in the child user control.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the [`MouseDoubleClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control.mousedoubleclick?view=net-5.0) event and the [`PreviewMouseDoubleClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control.previewmousedoubleclick?view=net-5.0) are defined on [`Control`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control?view=net-5.0). Since `UserControl` is a derivative of `Control`, the event is available and can be handled. However, `StackPanel` is not a derivative of `Control` so the event is not available, therefore the trigger does not work.

There are [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9213030/6181599) to this in code-behind that you can eventually turn into a behavior for MVVM, but simple workarounds like using input bindings on the left mouse click action only work on some elements, as others like `ComboBox` will already handle it and then the input bindings are **not triggered**.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <StackPanel.InputBindings>
      <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
                    Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
   </StackPanel.InputBindings>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <Label Content="Content"/>
      <ComboBox Name="cmbMyCombobox"/>
   </StackPanel>

   <!--More related controls-->

</StackPanel>
```

The most simple solution without creating additional code is to wrap the `StackPanel` in a control that is a derivative of `Control`, e.g. a `ContentControl`, like this.

```
<ContentControl>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
         <Label Content="Content"/>
         <ComboBox Name="cmbMyCombobox"/>
      </StackPanel>

      <!--More related controls-->

   </StackPanel>
   <b:Interaction.Triggers>
      <b:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
         <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
      </b:EventTrigger>
   </b:Interaction.Triggers>
</ContentControl>
```