# WPF Interaction Trigger MouseDoubleClick event not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, double, mouseevent, eventtrigger

I have a MouseDoubleClick event in the following .xaml file which is not firing properly:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:Source" x:Key="{x:Type controls:Source}">
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:Source">
      <Border BorderThickness="0.8" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
              d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance d:Type=viewModels:SourceViewModel}">
        <Grid Style="{StaticResource ElementThatClipsToParentBordersStyle}">
          <Image Source="{Binding AttachedSource.Image, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Stretch="Fill" />

          <Border x:Name="Selection"
                  Opacity="0.3"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                  Visibility="Collapsed"
                  IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
        </Grid>

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectionState.ClickSourceCommand, ElementName=SourcesControl}"
                                               CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
          </i:EventTrigger>

          <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
            <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PreviewLeftClickCommand}" />
          </i:EventTrigger>

          <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
            <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseMoveCommand}" />
          </i:EventTrigger>

          <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SourceDoubleClickCommand}"
                                               CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
          </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

      </Border>

      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
          <Setter TargetName="Selection" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Every others event works just fine and as intended but the command bound to the MouseDoubleClick event is not executed.

The weird thing is that when I use another event such as MouseLeftButtonDown everything is working, so the problem does not seem to be connected to the excuted command but to the used event itself.

Of course I could work around this problem by using a simple MouseLeftButtonDown event and check for the time of the last click to identify a doubleclick but the built-in doubleclick event seems to be better way to go for me.

Does someone have an idea why the MouseDoubleClick event is not firing properly in this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Border` does not have a `MouseDoubleClick` event, because it is not a control.
There are a couple of ways of making a `MouseDoubleClick`available. See [Why doesn't WPF border control have a mousedoubleclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410768/why-doesnt-wpf-border-control-have-a-mousedoubleclick-event).

A straightforward way is to wrap your border in a `ContentControl` which raises the `MouseDoubleClick`event (from http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2011/08/03/wpf-tip-using-a-mousedoubleclick-event-where-none-exists/):

```
<ContentControl MouseDoubleClick="OnDoubleClick">
  <Border Margin="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
    <Grid Margin="4">
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" />
        <TextBlock Text="Hello" FontSize="15" />
    </Grid>
  </Border>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, adding a content control worked like a charm!

Is there any way I could have realized a Border does not support a MouseDoubleClick event apart from "manually" looking in the supported events for a Border?

Visual Studio itself did not give me any hints...

Comment: I think you can see the events in the designer window. In my case, I found out about it by searching something like "wpf border click-event", and I probably still would try that first. One problem is realising that the problem is with the Border rather than with your code.

Comment: Clever, works perfectly for any other UI element, not just border.