# WPF: Focus border after click

Tags: c#, wpf, onclick, click, focus

I'm trying to get my `border` focused after the user clicks on it. 
Currently it is possible to focus the `border` via `tabs`, but via click would be way more convenient for the user.

```
        <Border x:Name="BorderFileInfo" Focusable="True" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1">
            <Grid Margin="3,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <!-- CONTENT CTRL -->
            </Grid>
        </Border>
```

I saw in another post that there is a possability to catch the click event with an `InputBinding` but I don't know how to focus the `border` afterwards without using a command.

[Stackoverflow: Why doesnt WPF border control have a mousedoubleclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410768/why-doesnt-wpf-border-control-have-a-mousedoubleclick-event)

Is there an easy way to do that other than having to create commands ?

The app is pretty small so I don't want to use commands if I don't have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy way is to handle `PreviewMouseDown` or similar mouse events and set the focus:

```
private void Border_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     Keyboard.Focus(sender as Border);
}
```

**edit**

note that you can create Click by handling PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown and PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp in this way:

```
_isdown =false;
private void Border_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     _isdown =true;
}
private void Border_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if ( _isdown)
    {
         _isdown = false;
         Keyboard.Focus(sender as Border);
     }
}
```