# Border Element How to add Click Event Programmaticaly

Tags: c#, wpf

I have  a code snippet like below. I am generating new border elements and adding it to parent Grid element. I want to handle click event when border element clicked. br.addHandler command is not working.

```
for (var h = 0; h < heightInt; h++)
        {
            for (var w = 0; w < widthInt; w++)
            {
                Border br = new Border()
                {
                    BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),
                    BorderBrush = Brushes.Black
                };

                br.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, w);
                br.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, h);
                br.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(borders_Click),true);

                EditorGr.Children.Add(br);
            }
        }
        private void borders_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("asdf");
        }
```

Comment: use `br.MouseDown` or `MouseUp` or even `MouseLeftButtonDown` instead. You can also use `+=` to assign an event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is related to the event handler that you are trying to add. You are trying to add a handler for the `Button.ClickEvent` to a `Border` which does not have this event.  You could use the `LeftMouseDownEvent` and that will work.

```
br.AddHandler(Border.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(borders_Click), true);
```

Or, taking from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21138252/416574) SO answer in regards to Double click on a border you could add the mouse input binding.

```
private class MyMouseCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    Action<object> _execute;
    public MyMouseCommand(Action<object> execute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute?.Invoke(parameter);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var mouse = new MouseBinding(
    new MyMouseCommand((r) => borders_Click()), new MouseGesture(MouseAction.LeftClick));
br.InputBindings.Add(mouse);
```

And lastly - update your click method signature (since it is no longer a routed event, you don't need any arguments):

```
private void borders_Click()
```